# Build:Cannot find module './src/directive_wrapper_compiler' Error

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript

My Angular2 project started failing build in VS2015 today after no changes that I know of, with the following errors. 
I say errors because there are multiple instances of the same error being thrown from different places.

```
Build:Cannot find module './src/directive_wrapper_compiler'.           
\node_modules\@angular\compiler\index.d.ts  45
```

Any thoughts at all what could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with the same issue, it seemed NPM was having issues getting the correct dependency versions.
I installed and ran [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) and that fixed the issue.